# Is there a concept which is the 'opposite' of SQL NULL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a concept (with an implementation - in Oracle SQL for starters) which behaves like a 'universal' matcher ?

What I mean is; I know NULL is not equal to anything - including NULL.
Which is why you have to be careful to 'IS NULL' rather than '=NULL' in SQL expressions.

I also know it is useful to use the NVL (in Oracle) function to detect a NULL and replace it with something in the output.

However: what you replace the NULL with using NVL has to match the datatype of the underlying column; otherwise you'll (rightly) get an error.

An example:

I have a table with a NULLABLE column 'name' of type VARCHAR2; and this contains a NULL row.

I can fetch out the NULL and replace it with an NVL like this:

```
SELECT NVL(name, 'NullyMcNullFace’) from my_table;
```

Great.

But if the column happens to a NUMBER (say 'age'), then I have to change my NVL:

```
SELECT NVL(age, 32) from my_table;
```

Also great.

Now if the column happens to be a DATE (say 'somedate'), then I have to change my NVL again:

```
SELECT NVL(somedate, sysdate) from my_table;
```

What I'm getting at here : is that in order to deal with NULLs you have to replace with a specific *something* ; and that specific *something* has to 'fit' the data-type.

So is there a construct/concept of (for want of a better word) like 'ANY' here.
Where 'ANY' would fit into a column of any datatype (like NULL), but (unlike NULL and unlike all other specific values) would match *ANYTHING* (including NULL - ? probably urghhh dunno).

So that I could do:

```
SELECT NVL(whatever_column, ANY) from my_table;
```

I think the answer is probably no; and probably 'go away, NULLs are bad enough - never mind this monster you have half-thought of'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no "universal acceptor" value in SQL that is equal to everything.

What you can do is raise the NVL into your comparison. Like if you're trying to do a JOIN:

```
SELECT ...
FROM my_table AS m
JOIN other_table AS o ON o.name = NVL(m.name, o.name)
```

So if `m.name` is NULL, then the join will compare `o.name` to `o.name`, which is of course always true.

For other uses of NULL, you might have to use another technique that suits the situation.

Comment: Thanks for this: my actual scenario is that I want to create a view of an audit table. But I want to output a 1 if the NEW and OLD value differ and a 0 if they are the same.  But (for my purposes) I want to also return 0 for two NULLS. And I’m using a CASE expression-don’t know how to “WHEN” that check , can’t work out the syntax for “IS NULL” in that scenario. Cheers

Comment: I should probably ask a new question. Thanks accepting the answer !

Comment: Yes if you have a specific need, then you should ask a question describing the scenario. Don't ask an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318605/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-oracle-case-expression, also thanks for the post about "XY" question - I never knew the term (but it is something I recognize very well - easy trap to fall into !) Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Adressing the question in the comment on Bill Karwin's answer:

> I want to output a 1 if the NEW and OLD value differ and a 0 if they are the same. But (for my purposes) I want to also return 0 for two NULLS.

```
select
    Case When (:New = :Old) or 
              (:New is NULL and :Old is NULL) then 0
         Else
              1
    End
from dual
```

Comment: That's it - you know what threw me was wrongly thinking that the CASE statement had to read 'CASE <SOMETHING> WHEN <TEST>'.

Comment: I'll log a new post on this - so you can answer it there, and I'll accept it.

Comment: Its here; if you want to re-answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318605/how-to-check-for-nulls-in-oracle-case-expression

Answer (score 1):

In a WHERE CLAUSE you can put a condition like this,

```
WHERE column1 LIKE NVL(any_column_or_param, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `DECODE()` would suit your purpose here?

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID, NULL val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, NULL val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 1 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 2 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 ID, 5 val FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 1 ID, NULL val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 3 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 1 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 4 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 ID, 5 val FROM dual)
SELECT t1.id t1_id,
       t1.val t1_val,
       t2.id t2_id,
       t2.val t2_val,
       DECODE(t1.val, t2.val, 0, 1) different_vals
FROM   t1
       FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id);

     T1_ID     T1_VAL      T2_ID     T2_VAL DIFFERENT_VALS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
         1                     1                         0
         2                     2          3              1
         3          1          3          1              0
         4          2          4          4              1
         5          5                                    1
                               6          5              1
```