# How to check for NULLs in Oracle 'CASE' Expression?

Tags: sql, oracle, null

This is a follow-on (actually it is the origin of my woes) from : [Is there a concept which is the 'opposite' of SQL NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306882/is-there-a-concept-which-is-the-opposite-of-sql-null)

How do a construct an Oracle 'Case Expression' to compare two columns for equality (and output say '0' in the instance) and (for my purposes) output a '0' when both columns are NULL ?

Here's some test data to illustrate what I mean:

```
create table t_table (x number(1), y number(1));
insert into  t_table values(0,0);
insert into  t_table values(0,1);
insert into  t_table values(0,NULL);
insert into  t_table values(1,0);
insert into  t_table values(1,1);
insert into  t_table values(1,NULL);
insert into  t_table values(NULL,0);
insert into  t_table values(NULL,1);
insert into  t_table values(NULL,NULL);
```

And now I compare X,Y and output 0 for 'equal' and '1' for 'not-equal'.

```
SELECT x, y , CASE x WHEN y THEN 0 WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END compare FROM t_table;

         X          Y    COMPARE
---------- ---------- ----------
         0          0          0
         0          1          1
         0                     1
         1          0          1
         1          1          0
         1                     1
                    0          1
                    1          1
                               1

 9 rows selected
```

NULLs are shown as blankspace in the above; you can see that 0,0->0 and 1,1->0 are what I want, but NULL,NULL->1 , which (in my case) is not what I want.

This is because NULL does not equal NULL ; so not sure how to do an 'IS NULL' in place of this ?

Comment: let me know if its not duplicate , i will reopen it again

Comment: You can't do that with a simple case expression, but you can do that with either a decode or a searched case expression, e.g. `decode(x, y, 0, 1)` or `case when x = y or (x is null and y is null) then 0 else 1`